# Receiving error when trying to getUI [Exception: Cannot call DocumentApp.getUi() from this context]

Tags: google-apps-script

thank you for helping

I am trying to create an alert that outputs my recipients to an email that will be sent.

For some reason, when I try to getUi(), I get this error

> "Exception: Cannot call DocumentApp.getUi() from this context."

Some more information:

- The script is bound to a Google Doc
- I have searched in the forum and haven't found an answer to this question.
- The function will be triggered from the Doc UI (added a menu)
- When deleting the "let ui = DocumentApp.getUi()", the function works as expected

Here is the code:

```
function onOpen(){
  DocumentApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Extras')
  .addItem('Send Email [Internal]', 'sendNotes')
  .addToUi();

}

function sendNotes() {
  let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  let ui = DocumentApp.getUi(); //error was raised here
  let body = doc.getBody();
  let meetingDate = body.getChild(3).getText();
  let recepients = 'or@*****.com';
  Logger.log(meetingDate);
  let file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recepients , meetingDate + ' | eToro | Meeting Notes', 
  `Hey Team,  

I hope you are well
  
Here are the meeiting notes for this weeks weekly. (Also updated in Drive)
  
Cheers,`, {
  attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
  name: 'Meeting notes ' +meetingDate
  })



}
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please provide more details. Is this code on a bounded project if so to which kind of file it's bound to? How is the function being exectuted?

Comment: By the way, there are already several questions about the same error message, you should spend some time searching this site to find out if the answer that you need was already posted.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details but something is still missing.... please test your script by using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled, open the doc and click the corresponding menu. Does the error happens again?

Comment: No need to paste in the comments the content already added to the question... questions have a revision history :)

Comment: Hey @Rubén, I can't explain this - but it works now (I haven't changed anything - but I did test it in incognito and it worked) - Thank you for your help!